# Sending data into my app without actually launching it

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

Little help please, because I am not really familiar with this kind of thing.

When user selects (long-touches) the current web-address - there is a "Share page" option that pop-ups in the alertDialog - this is what Android originally provides.

Now, I've signed up my application to handle this "Share page" event. Now, when user chooses my app from the share page list - I want the web-address to be saved in the text file somewhere in the file structure, so that I could access it later within my app.

How do I implement this if I don't want to launch my entire app to save that link address? Can it be run sort of in background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple. Don't set any content to your sharing activity in `onCreate`. Instead, perform all the saving part inside `onCreate` and call `finish();` at the very end.

Hopefully, the entire process will be fast enough (or introduce `AsyncTask` if it takes longer) that the user won't feel any lag and launch of a new activity  :)

Comment: I just want to do it properly this time :)

Comment: If your applications doesn't have a **Service** then don't introduce it just to execute this simple task

Comment: I think I will listen to your advice :)

Comment: Good. Moreover, if you are experiencing a black screen even for a very short while, then I would suggest you to set the theme `@android:style/Theme.Panel` to that particular activity in order to make it invisible

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for all the care xx

Answer (score 2):

Easily. Instead of catching it in an `Activity`, catch in in a `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have an activity with `<intent-filter>` in the Manifest to handle the Share Intent.

You could do what you want in two ways:

- Use a Sevice and make it handle the Share Intent. i.e. saving the url.
- In your Activity:

  - Do not call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`. This may not be invisible 100%. A black screen *may* show up.
  - Start your Service.

Comment: <service android:name=".ShareLink">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

Comment: This is my manifest. But now it is not displayed as an option in "Share page". What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that [Android calls the Activities ONLY when handling the share intent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7260838/543711). Sorry for the confusion. I Edited the answer.